# Can't access BIOS after install of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot

I just got a reconditioned Dell Dimension 4500. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as the only operating system and now if I try to access the BIOS, I get an error saying `utilities partition not found`. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You probably erased the system utilities and backup partition, which it probably uses to modify the BIOS settings in a nice, graphical way.  You'll need to contact the manufacturer for recovery CDs and/or a method of restoring the utilities partition.